# I need to design a second order active filter low-pass Rauch structure of Bessel. Design data: f-cut = 15 Hz; C1 = 50 pF. More info in img

Tags: low-pass, active-filter, circuits, labview

[image] How can I find the values requierd? I tried using the formulas my teacher gave me but c2 is 0 when i use them. Am i doing something wrong? should i use other formulas? I tried to ask the teacher but he is no willing to help at all. I need to give it in monday so please help

[image][image]

Comment: And we are supposed to use OCR to understand what that means? Try [this](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/). Also, what have you tried in solving this homework?

Comment: Hello, I used the exemple my teacher gave and used this formulas but the answer was 0, i did a lot of research online as well but i still didn't find anything to help. I read all his notes and exemples but nothing helped whatever i tried it was still c2=0

Comment: I’m voting to close this question

Comment: No need to be so nice ...thanks

Comment: Turns out that my teacher gave me the wrong formulas i found it online https://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/downloads/sloa088.pdf here there is a minus and some diferences i will try using this.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Next time, write a far better question that shows your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that you are using the value 1 for A<sub>0</sub>. This is not surprising as the notes are incorrect. This circuit actually has negative gain because it's an inverting amplifier. The formula should be A<sub>0</sub>=-R<sub>2</sub>/R<sub>1</sub>. With the given information that R<sub>1</sub>=R<sub>2</sub>=R<sub>3</sub>=R, then the gain is actually A<sub>0</sub>=-R/R=-1. Now using this value, you could find the minimum value C<sub>2</sub> must be using the last equation. Note that it may help to choose value for C<sub>2</sub> then find value for R. You could also start with a value for R and then find value for C<sub>2</sub>. I'm not sure on how practical the values for resistors and C<sub>2</sub> need to be for your professor to be satisfied but it may help to find reasonable values for them and not extremely high values like 100M ohm resistor or 1F capacitor. With this information you can solve the rest.

Comment: this was so helpful thank you so much for your time